# breezejs : registerEntityTypeCtor for Added entities only?

Tags: breeze

I've used the registerEntityTypeCtor function to add some initialization code when an Entity is created. However this code is fired regardless of the state of the Entity (Added vs Changed vs Detached, etc....)

I'd like the initialization code inside registerEntityTypeCtor to only applied to Entity with the state Added. The problem is that the state of the Entity is only set AFTER the bespoke constructor was called. Anything I could do to work around that ?

```
 function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Mandate', function () {
            this.blah = 'test';
        }, mandatInitializer);

        //Validator.register(someValidator);
        logger.info('Validators applied');
    }

    function mandatInitializer(mandat) {     
        mandat.TransactionType = '0';
        mandat.Status = '0';
        mandat.NextSequenceType = '0';
        mandat.MandateType = '0';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method registerEntityTypeCtor has three input parameters: the entity name,the constructor, and the initializer method. I think that you can use the third parameter for doing the inizialization only in added entities.

```
dtContext.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityName, constructor, initializerMethod);
```

---EDIT---

You can check if the id is unefined in the initializerMethod:

```
function initializerMethod(entity){
  if(entity.id()===unefined || entity.id()=== null){
    //Do things that you want with the new entity
    //...
    //Initilize the id with a temporal value that would be override in the server side.
  }
}
```

Comment: that's what I do already. But at that stage, the Entity state is not set yet. See my code above.

Comment: You can do the initialization of your id in entity in the initializer method. Doing that, you can check in this method if the id is undefined, and you can know if it is a new entity .

Comment: ok, that's one way to do it. I would have preferred doing the check on the Entity status though. It's just neater.

Comment: I think so, but I don't know any way to do this check in the constructor or in the initializer method.

Comment: I ended u using the id check as I haven't found any better way to do it. I'll mark your post as answer.